# How to exit the current user with Google Cloud SDK Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I refer to this [page](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries?refresh=1#client-libraries-usage-python) to operate.

I have a account, and I run the following commands using the Google Cloud SDK Shell, but the json file is my friend's account. I do not have permission.

So I want to exit the current user,and login with my friend's account, but now how to exit the current user and change an account to login?

> Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK! Run "gcloud -h" to get the list of
>   available commands.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud iam service-accounts
>   create XXX ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.create) The required
>   property [project] is not currently set. You may set it for your
>   current workspace by running:
>
> $ gcloud config set project VALUE
>
> or it can be set temporarily by the environment variable
>   [CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud projects
>   add-iam-policy-binding dynamic-return-XXX --member
>   "serviceAccount:XXX@dynamic-return-XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role
>   "roles/owner" ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) User
>   [wallace.convict.439759406@gmail.com] does not have permission to
>   access project [dynamic-return-XXX:getIamPolicy] (or it may not
>   exist): The caller does not have permission
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I know how to exit current user.
The command is:

> gcloud auth login